# How to pass arguments to a function inside a dictionary?

Tags: python

As switch case is not available in Python, I made use of dictionary for this to perform arithmetic operation:

```
a = 10
b = 5

def add(a, b):
    return a + b 

def sub(a, b):
    return a - b

def mul(a, b):
    return a * b

def div(a, b):
    return a / b

def default():
    return "not a valid option"

opt = {
   1: add,
   2: sub,
   3: mul,
   4: div
}

op = 2

def getdetails(op):
    return opt.get(op, default)()

getdetails(op)
```

How do I pass my `a` and `b` value to my function when I enter option which hits the dictionary to call particular function?

Comment: "switch case is not available in Python" Yes, it is, since version 3.10, see structural pattern matching.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#simple-pattern-match-to-a-literal see the release notes of python 3.10

Answer (score 1):

[Since Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html), there actually *is* a "switch-case" feature, called [*pattern matching*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching):

```py
a = 10
b = 5

op = 2

match op:
    case 1:
        print(a + b)
    case 2:
        print(a - b)
    case 3:
        print(a * b)
    case 4:
        print(a / b)
    case _:
        print("not a valid option")
```

The last case, [`_`, is a *wildcard*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/#adding-a-wildcard).

---

For earlier versions you can easily *"emulate"* something similar to a switch-case:

```py
a = 10
b = 5

op = 2

def case(value):
    return op == value

if case(1):
    print(a + b)
elif case(2):
    print(a - b)
elif case(3):
    print(a * b)
elif case(4):
    print(a / b)
else:
    print("not a valid option")
```

---

Or, for keeping with your approach, I would do some small changes to your code:

- No need to implement all those functions - there is the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module for that.
- I wouldn't even bother with a `default` function - as others mentioned, the different signature will cause you headaches ahead.
- Instead, I would go for [forgiveness instead of permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain) and *assume* the `op` exists, and if there is a `KeyError` - we know it is the default.
- Finally, your actual mistake is that you simply didn't pass the arguments - `opt.get(op, default)()` should simply be `opt.get(op, default)(a, b)`, apart from the problem mentioned above with `default`.

```py
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv

a = 10
b = 5

opt = {
   1: add,
   2: sub,
   3: mul,
   4: truediv
}

op = 2

try:
    print(opt[op](a, b))
except KeyError:
    print("not a valid option")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tou should change:

```py
def default():
    return "not a valid option"

def getdetails(op):
    return opt.get(op,default)()

getdetails(op)
```

To

```py
def default(*_):
    return "not a valid option"

def getdetails(op):
    return opt.get(op, default)

res = getdetails(op)(a,b)
```

And it will work.

Full code example:

```py
a = 10
b = 5


def add(a, b):
    return a + b


def sub(a, b):
    return a - b


def mul(a, b):
    return a * b


def div(a, b):
    return a / b


def default(*_):
    return "not a valid option"


opt = {
    1: add,
    2: sub,
    3: mul,
    4: div
}


def getdetails(op):
    return opt.get(op, default)


op = 2

res = getdetails(op)(a,b)

print(res)
```

Comment: can you explain me what is it `*_`

Comment: @coreke2042 `*_` - for ignoring arguments of the function  `default` (because you don't use it anyway).  `*` - used to pass a variable number of arguments to a function, `_` - for ignoring them
More info can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726155/is-an-acceptable-way-to-ignore-arguments-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok to me, but I made a change in your `default` function, so that there is no error when `op` is not available in your dictionary. Also add the function call:

```
a=10
b=5

def add(a,b):
    return a+b 

def sub(a,b):
    return a-b

def mul(a,b):
    return a*b

def div(a,b):
    return a/b

def default(*args): # a, b are input, to prevent an positional arguments error add *args.
    return "not a valid option"

opt={
   1: add,
   2: sub,
   3: mul,
   4: div
}

op=2
# Call the function:
print(opt.get(op, default)(a,b))
>>> 5
print( opt.get(None, default)(a,b) )
>>> 'not a valid option'
```

EDIT:

Why the `*args` part in the function? `*args` is one method to capture variable for a function which are not defiend:

```
def test(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg, end=' ') # end=' ' adds an space instead of a new line after print.

test(1, 2, 5)
>>> 1, 2, 3
```

What happens when a function is called without `*args`?:

```
def test():
    print('TEST')

test(1, 2)
>>> TypeError: test() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

You are expecting a function from your dictionary *and* you are going to add the arguments `a` and `b`. Therefore you have to deal with them in each function in the dictionary.

What you also could do is:

```
def default(a,b):
    # Just ignore a,b
    return 'not valid'
```

That will also work, but if you want to add more arguments for other functions in the future the advantage of `*args` is taht it can take as much arguments as you want, there is no maximum.

Comment: can you explain in detail about *args why it is used in default ()

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Considering that `default` is a special case, I would handle it manually instead of with `get`:

```
# instead of baking your own, use stdlib
from operator import add, sub, mul, div, mod

opt = {
   '+': add,
   '-': sub,
   '*': mul,
   '/': div,
   '%': mod,
}

def getresult(op, a, b):
    try:
        return opt[op](a, b)
    except KeyError:
        return default()

getresult('*', 10, 5)
```

If you do want to use `get`, you have to normalize the signature of `default` to accept the same arguments as the other options:

```
def default(*args, **kwargs):
    return 'Invalid option'

def getresult(op, a, b):
    return opt.get(op)(a, b)
```