# colour_selected() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given. how i fix this?

Tags: python, tkinter-canvas

trying to make option list of colours that change the colour of a pattern in canvas

```py
preview = Canvas(window, width=100, height=100, bg="white")
preview.place(x=230,y=170)
global s_fill
s_fill = "purple"
p_selected = 1
```

```
def update():
    if p_selected == 1:
        pattern1
    else:
        pattern2

def colour_selected():
    global s_fill
    selected = var2.get()
    if selected == "purple":
        preview.delete("all")
        s_fill = "purple"
        update()
    elif selected == "DarkSlateGray4":
        preview.delete("all")
        s_fill = "DarkSlateGray4"
        update()
    elif selected == "deep sky blue":
        preview.delete("all")
        s_fill = "deep sky blue"
        update()
    elif selected == "light sea green":
        preview.delete("all")
        s_fill = "light sea green"
        update()
    elif selected == "VioletRed2":
        preview.delete("all")
        s_fill = "VioletRed2"
        update()
    elif selected == "gold":
        preview.delete("all")
        s_fill = "gold"
        update()


var2 = StringVar()
c_options = ("purple", "DarkSlateGray4", "deep sky blue", "light sea green", "VioletRed2", "gold")
colour_list = OptionMenu(window, var2, * c_options, command= colour_selected)
colour_list.place(x=40, y=210, width=120, height=25)
```

i keep getting the error *colour_selected() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given* and i generally just don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `colour_selected` ignore any arguments passed to it:

```
def colour_selected(*_):
```

(See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13726155/113848) for more about `*_`.)

Comment: that gets rid of the error but if you change the colour it makes the canvas blank insted of changing the pattern colour