# Is the name of the second parameter to __deepcopy__ required to be memo?

Tags: python, deep-copy

Is it required to name the second argument of the `__deepcopy__` function `memo`, in case `__deepcopy__` is called with `memo` as a keyword argument?

If I simply want to exclude instances from deep copies, would:

```py
obj.__deepcopy__ = lambda self, _: self
```

be fine, or do I need to pay attention to naming the second argument of the lambda function `memo` in order to not cause any issues?

My initial thoughts are that the parameter's name is part of the function signature, and `memo` is not documented to be a positional argument, so it should probably be safer to name the second argument `memo`, and just add a linter exception for marking the argument unused.

Comment: If you want to prohibit from performing a deepcopy, either don't implement it or raise an exception.

Comment: If you are intending to ignore arguments, then beyond using `_`, you can use `*args,**kwargs` which can signal to other programmers what you are doing. Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76104136) to a similar question.

Comment: I'd expect that method _only_ to be called by `deepcopy` (which [in CPython at least](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/985679f05d1b72965bfbed99d1499c22815375e4/Lib/copy.py#L141-L143) passes `memo` positionally), not directly.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to work within the object, you can do the deep copy as the following code:

```
class memo:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __deepcopy__(self, obj):
        _obj = self.__class__(**self.__dict__) # this line create a copy of the object
        _obj.a = 4 # this line let you modify the object
        return _obj
```

With this you can create a copy with the custom modification `copy.deepcopy(memo_obj)`.

The `deepcopy` function simply invokes a method within the class called `__deepcopy__`, passing one parameter. You are free to choose any name for that parameter that you prefer.

The issue with the `lambda` is that it is a lambda function and not a method inside the class. Consequently, you cannot pass the `self` parameter to copy the object.

Using `lambda self, memo: self` would be incorrect because the `deepcopy` function is called with the following code:

```py
    151 copier = getattr(x, "__deepcopy__", None)
    152 if copier is not None:
--> 153     y = copier(memo)
```

In this case, memo takes on the value of self, and the lambda expression has two parameters. This configuration will be outside the scope of the copier function, which expects only one parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my instance, I want to allow particular containers to be deepcopied, but just a content of a particular type to be always omitted, therefore I have to implement `__deepcopy__` by returning `self` and cannot go with your and matswecja's suggestion of completely prohibiting a deepcopy. I think in your implementation, the question would probably still remain if `obj` should be called `memo` instead (in case it is called somewhere as kwarg). Reconsidering my question I think I phrased some of it inconcisely, I don't want to prohibit a deepcopy,but rather return the og obj

Comment: This doesn't seem to approach the actual question (except indirectly by _not_ naming it `memo`).