# Django unused method arguments

Tags: python, django

What to do with unused variables in Django (I speak mostly about class based views)?

```
 def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # request, args, kwargs are not used in this post method
        ..
        return ..
```

Is it safe to `del` them ?

In [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025680/how-can-i-denote-unused-function-arguments) I also see, that *_ can be used for things I don't care.

Why? For the sake of cleaning the code and avoiding IDE warnings.

I can safely `del` `*args` and `**kwargs`, but how about `request`? `request` I can acces it later using `self.request`, when using a class based view - actually I do that, but can I be sure that I will have no problem?

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611345/django-why-is-the-request-post-object-immutable) that django request is immutable, but no in all cases.

My question is, what do do with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of calling them - you don't use them, as you probably already know.   `*args` and `**kwargs` are entirely optional, so don't pass them. In the example above, you can call that view method with just a request object.

In terms of writing them and clean code: If these are your CBVs, leave them off the declaration; if they're [arguments inherited from the generic](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py) base class, then surely you won't see them in your code anyway?

If you're asking from a garbage collection point of view, then they'll expire after the view function has run and is no longer referenced by the view namespace.   [Ned's coverage of variables in python is always relevant.](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

In terms of idiomatic python, explicitly `del`ing the variables would be quite unusual, and make the code significantly less readable.  It also won't, for instance, [free the memory](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm), although I appreciate that wasn't one of the reasons you were asking.

On the specifics of the request object - the request object is required to use render in Function based views.  In CBVs, it's an attribute rather than a variable, for the semantic difference that makes, but even if you're not using it directly, Django needs the [request object to generate the HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/).

Also, [the generic view base class docs have further details on that flow down through the stack.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/)